# How to create custom tabs in the centre of the screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, tabs, tabbar

I am doing react native application. In that, One screen have custom tabs in centre of the screen.

My screen is like,

- top view around 200px height with some text lines showing.
- After that, Custom tabs as picture attached.
- After that, I am showing for first tab on tap flat list data.

I have checked online forums and tutorials, According to tab bar, We can show either top or bottom screen with tabs.
But, How to show tabs with customisation like my requirement.

I have 4 tabs, and each tab has same top view which I mentioned in above (some text lines), And if I tap on each tab, different data bottom page should show.

Like,

- First tab with some flat list,
- second tab with some text lines,
- likewise all tabs has different layout in bottom screen.

As I am very new to react native. How to achieve this?
Due to privacy policy, I am unable to post complete screenshot.

Here is my code.

> Screen.js

```
 onClickTelugu = () => {
    alert("you clicked onClickTelugu")
   }
   onClickTamil = () => {
    alert("you clicked onClickTamil")

   }
   onClickHindi = () => {
    alert("you clicked onClickHindi")

    }
   onClickEnglish = () => {
    alert("you clicked onClickEnglish");
    }


 render(item) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style ={styles.Container}> 
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                    Some Text
              </Text>
              <View style={styles.somestyles}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onClick}>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.somestyles}
                        source={MenuImage}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onClick}>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.menuIcon}
                        source={MenuImage}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style ={styles.somestyles}>
              <View style={styles.somestyles}>
              <Text style= {styles.somestyles}> 
                    Some Text
              </Text>
              <Text style= {styles.somestyles}> 
                    Some Text
              </Text>
              <Text style= {styles.somestyles} >
              <Text style= {styles.somestyles}>
                    Some Text
              </Text>
              <Text style ={styles.somestyles}>
                    Some Text
              </Text>
              </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.somestyles}>
              <Text style={styles.somestyles}>some text</Text>
              <Text style={styles.somestyles} >some text</Text>
              <Text style={styles.somestyles}>date</Text>
              <Text style={styles.somestyles}>some other date</Text>
              </View>
              </View>
              </View>
           <View style = {styles.tabContainer}>
           <View style ={styles.tabInnerContainer}>
           <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabIcons} onPress={this.onClickTelugu}>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.tabItemsImages}
                                source={image}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.tabTextItems} onPress={this.onClickTelugu}>Telugu</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.tabInnerContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabIcons} onPress={this.onClickTamil}>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.tabItemsImages}
                               source={image}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.tabTextItems} onPress={this.onClickTamil}>Tamil</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.tabInnerContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabIcons} onPress={this.onClickHindi}>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.tabItemsImages}
                                source={image}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.tabTextItems} onPress={this.onClickHindi}>Hindi</Text>

                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.tabInnerContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabIcons} onPress={this.onClicEnglish}>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.tabItemsImages}
                               source={image}
                            />

               </TouchableOpacity>
               <Text style={styles.tabTextItems} onPress={this.onClicEnglish}>English</Text>

                  </View>
              </View>
              <View style = {styles.flatListContainer}>  
                  <FlatList style = {styles.flatList}
                        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = {true}
                        data = {this.state.dataArray}
                        renderItem = {({item}) => (
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => this.flatListItemHandler(item)}>
                               <Image
                                style={styles.flatListArrowImage}
                               source={image}
                            />
                               </View>
                                <View style={styles.flatListItemInsideSeparator}>

                        )
                    }
                    ItemSeparatorComponent = {() => (
                        <View style={{height:15, backgroundColor:'#F8F8F8'}}/>
                    )}
                />
              </View>
          </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

> And I have to show overlay tab images too. If 1st tab tapped, 2,3,4
>   tabs images should be like delighted images. Like
>   highlighted/delighted images.

[image]

Comment: How about creating custom buttons. You can easily centered align using `flexbox` while wrapping it  inside `View`

Comment: I did like that, But, for those tabs actions, I have to load different pages(Data) in bottom screen. There I got stucked.

Comment: if you can share some code where you got stucked , Community can help you on that :)

Comment: Code updated, please check once

Comment: @Firu Code updated, please check once

Comment: you are just alerting the text on onPress, instead you can show/hide the views

Comment: How can I show new view and hide old view according to tabs tap there, As I mentioned I am new to this domain, Can you share any examples and I have to set overlay images on tabs too.

Comment: Can we call like this   onClickTelugu = () => {
    alert("you clicked onClickTelugu")
  
      <View style={[styles.flatListContainer, { backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }]}>
    <Text>Feature coming soon</Text>
    </View>
 }

Comment: [Conditional rendering in React Native](https://medium.com/@szholdiyarov/conditional-rendering-in-react-native-286351816db4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you need to give this component it's own state to keep track of what you want to show in the lower section. then you should replace all of your onClick events with just one onClick event that you pass different languages to. For Example `this.onClickTelugu` becomes `() => this.onClick('telugu')`, then your onClick event should be:

`onClick = (language) => { 
  this.setState({selectedLanguage: language}) 
}`

then in your `renderBottomContent` function, you can render different things depending on what this.state.selectedLanguage is.

something like...

```
    class MyComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { selectedLanguage: null}
      }

      onClick = (language) => { 
        this.setState({selectedLanguage: language}) 
      }

      renderBottomContent = () => {
        const {selectedLanguge} = this.state
        switch(selectedLanguage) {
          case "telugu":
            return <View><Text>Telugu</Text></View>
          case "tamil":
            return <View><Text>Tamil</Text></View>
          case "hindi":
            return <View><Text>Hindi</Text></View>
          case "english":
            return <View><Text>English</Text></View>
          default:
            return <View><Text>No Language Selected...</Text></View>
        }
      }

      render() { 
         ...
        <View style ={styles.tabInnerContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabIcons} onPress={() => this.onClick('telugu')}>
            <Image style={styles.tabItemsImages} source={image} />
          <Text style={styles.tabTextItems}>
            Telugu
          </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style ={styles.tabInnerContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabIcons} onPress={() => this.onClick('tamil')}>
            <Image style={styles.tabItemsImages} source={image} />
          <Text style={styles.tabTextItems}>
            Tamil
          </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    ... 
        // after all the other tab buttons, render bottom content depending on the component state
        {this.renderBottomContent()}
     }
  }
```

Comment: Did you understand my query properly, I got stuck loading different layouts in bottom screen, Like, I have 4 tabs, 1st tab data like tableview (Flatlist), 2nd tab has different data, etc.

Comment: yeah, just replace the text tags with whatever content you want to see. It could be an image, or table view or flat list or anything. It doesn't matter what you want to show -- I'm just showing you how to control showing different things with your tab buttons. What you want to return for each case in the switch statement is up to you. `<Text>Tamil</Text>` can be replaced with `<Flatlist/>` if you want

Comment: I have to change tabs images like active/inactive state.

Comment: Where can I set default one is first tab data to load after screen loaded?

Comment: If I try to render <Text> its comings, but, <FlatList> not coming at all. Why, Is it won't support?

Comment: I am passing like this               {this.renderBottomContent(item)}
But, not working at all

Comment: Anyway, I am upvoted your solution, But, From each tab, I have to navigate other screens like flat list on click will navigate to other screen, but, top view is same/consistent for all screens. Will this approach makes good practice, Any memory issues would occur? Won't increase much transactions data in single class?

Comment: A Flatlist requires an array of list elements like this `<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>`. If you don't give it any data it won't display anything.

Comment: I got it already, array is getting empty, I fixed it. And each tab has details page, So, will this approach makes good practice or memory issues will come? Because we are writing somany classes data into single class. Like first tab onclick on flatlist, will navigate to details screen with same header view, likewise other tabs has details screens.

Comment: No memory issues, but it's always good to keep components on the small side if you can as it's easier to read the code and reason about it that way. It would be good practice to "componentize" your bottom content, then at the top you can `import TeluguScreen from './TeluguScreen'` and then in your switch statement `case "telugu":
            return <TeluguScreen />`

Comment: But, how to show details screen with same header view like tabs each screen does, same way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187600/discussion-between-nunchucks-and-anilkumar-ios-developer).